# ¿Como hago para rediccionar de mi App a la sección de Marcar números telefónicos en Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy con un perfil que tengo el icono del teléfono (y que por supuesto contiene el numero de celular) y al presionar quiero que marque el celular el numero de telefono.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? Estoy trabajando con Dart y flutter.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class fila_botones extends StatelessWidget {
  String celular;
  fila_botones(this.celular);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final barraiconos = Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 50.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 20.0,
        left: 20.0,
        right: 20.0,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            child: Container(
              child: Tooltip(
                 child: Icon(
                 Icons.call,
                  size: 50.0,
                  ),
              message: 'El celu es: ' + celular.toString()),

              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 50.0,
                left: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              _launchURL();
            }
          ),



          InkWell(
            child: Container(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.map,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 50.0,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {

            }
            ,
          ),
          InkWell(
            child: Container(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.print,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 50.0,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {

            }
            ,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return barraiconos;
  }

  _launchURL() async {
    var url = celular;
    print(celular);
    if (celular != null){
     if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }


    }else{
      AlertDialog(
        content: Text('No contiene numero telefonico'),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el paquete [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher)
Seǵun la misma documentación tu implementación sería parecido a este:

```
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: _launchURL,
    child: Text('Llamar'),
),
...
// Función que lanza el intento de llamada con la url: tel:<phone number>
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'tel:+1 555 010 999';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: E/flutter (20759): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception: E/flutter (20759): Could not launch 2929432502
E/flutter (20759): #0      fila_botones._launchURL (package:vivi_carhue/lista_negocio_detalle/fila_botones.dart:83:7)
E/flutter (20759): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20759): #1      fila_botones.build.<anonymous closure> (package:vivi_carhue/lista_negocio_detalle/fila_botones.dart:35:15)
E/flutter (20759): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)

Comment: No entra al if @EdHuamani

Comment: Has instalado el plugin url_launcher https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher?

Comment: Sisi, lo tengo instalado. No se porque no entra al condicional. Imprime el throw 'Could not launch $url';

Comment: Agregué un Tooltip para corroborar que el celular llegue correctamente y lo es. (Por que los datos me llegan de la base de datos remota) La varialbe Url se le pasa como parametro un String verdad?

Comment: Es posible que no estés anteponiendo el `tel`, tu variable url debería tener el siguiente formato `String url = tel:<phone number>` por ejemplo: `String url = tel:+51915487459`

Comment: Perfecto!!!!!!!!!!!